# pulling file size, in mb, in batch, then use it as a conditionnal for further commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm new and very novice with batch and don't fully understand how conditionals and executions work within it. So please bear with me.
I'm starting up with these two lines

```
"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~1" -threads 8 -ss 00:04:03.000 -to 00:04:17.000 -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -r 30 -b:v 2050K -vf scale=-1:520 -an -f webm -pass 1 -y NUL
"%~dp0\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~1" -threads 8 -ss 00:04:03.000 -to 00:04:17.000 -c:v libvpx -crf 4 -r 30 -b:v 2050K -vf scale=-1:520 -an -pass 2 -y "%~n1.webm"
```

most of it you don't need to worry about. I'm just using ffmpeg commands to produce a webm from a drag & dropped video file (the "%~1" at the start). It works! I'm only missing the batch portion of this (conditionals/variables) to do what I want to do:

I'm trying to algorithmically pick the best bitrate (which is the -b:v 2050K) to get as close to 3mb as possible. (I known by using constant bitrate, there is a way to force a specific file size, it is lower quality though)

The simplest steps that I could think about to achieve this (and probably in no way the most optimized)
1- run the two lines once with a ridiculous bitrate like 6000k
2- get file size of the first webm (put it into a variable?)
3- calculate new bitrate with simple rule of three (newbitrate = (oldbitrate x 2.99)/sizeoffirstwebm)
4- run the two lines once a gain with the newbitrate
5- get the file size of the second webm
6- calculate new bitrate with simple rule of three (newbitrate = (oldbitrate*2.99)/sizeofSECONDwebm)
7- produce final webm which should be close to my target file size
The reason i'm doing that twice is because bitrate and size are closely, but not perfectly, linearly correlated, so it helps me hone on my 3mb target more closely
Sure, it will take like 3 times the time to render anything, but I think it's worth it since I'm already doing that manually.

Comment: I would doubt that a simple multiplication/division algorithm, like the one you're suggesting, would adequately be able to calculate the settings you need to create your ideal resulting file size. Also, your question appears to be seeking opinion on a methodology, not looking for assistance with a specific issue with your programming code. This site deals with the latter, so currently your question requires that you [edit] it, to concentrate focus on a single specific programming issue, in line with the guidance under [ask].

Comment: `file size = bitrate * duration`. Why not follow this simple rule instead of your complicated method?